# Javascript function defining

Tags: javascript

I just got this script for debugging and have no idea what this following section means.

```
var qns = () => site + status + "\
"
let status = "true";
```

The variable status has not defined before.

Comment: Please provide your script

Comment: [ECMAScript 6 support in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is JavaScript 1.7, available currently on Firefox, but not on most other browsers.

```
var qns = () => site + status + "\
"
```

is equivalent, but shorter than:

```
var qns = function() {
  return site + status + "\n";
}
```

(not sure if newline is valid or not). [Arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

`let status = true` is same as `var status = true` aside from the scope: it will only be declared for the containing block. For example,

```
if (true) {
  var x = 1;
  let y = 2;
  console.log(x); // => 1
  console.log(y); // => 2
}
console.log(x); // => 1
console.log(y); // => undefined
```

By the way, the variable `status` does not need to be declared before your line; it is enough if it is declared before `qns()` is invoked later. [`let` statement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)